# Why is there no 4-player pre-made group on Flex Queue?

Tags: league-of-legends

In the current season, there is a 'Flex Queue' which allows you to queue to a ranked game with 1, 2, 3 or 5 player pre-made groups. Why is a 4-player pre-made group not available?

Comment: That's a question only the developers can answer.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer FYI, there used to be a 4-player premade which was removed this season. I am looking for past announcements which might have touched up on the subject.

Comment: You're saying yourself that it's a question only the developers can answer.

Comment: I am saying there would have been some communication when a feature in the game was removed in a later update. I am looking for this communication, if there was any.

Comment: If only a developer can answer a question, we don't allow it. Whether they actually *have* answered it is immaterial.

Comment: Looking at the answer given, it seems like people other than devs can answer using logic.

Comment: It's a shame that this question was marked as off-topic, as it is not. It's a very simple to answer question, it's a group ranked mode, if groups of 4 existed, there would be a solo player, which isn't group mode anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Four-man premades are disabled in Flex queue because a solo-player would have to fill the last position. The 4-man group would have peer-pressure and would be able to bully the solo player into picking a role they may not want. Because the solo player is the odd man out, they usually also end up as a scapegoat if things start going wrong in game, and the 4-man group harasses the solo player in retribution.

Another reason is that Flex queue is meant to be played in groups of more than one person. If 4-man groups were allowed, that would implicitly encourage solo-players to join Flex queue in order to fill those extra slots.